# Get width of text to use in CSS scroll animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text animation that scrolls text from left to right and back so the full text can be seen and isn't cut off.  I have an example below:

```css
.selectionContainer {
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.link_animated {
  animation: backAndForth 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes backAndForth {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  45% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  55% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.HS-Silk-Image {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="column-1-table" class="table HS-Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="" colspan="4">
        <div class="">Monday</div>
        <div class="HS-Going-Text">2022-06-20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="" colspan="3">
    </tr>
    <tr class="" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
      <td class="" colspan="4">
        <div class="pull-left Selection-Container">Argentina Liga Profesional de Futbol</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-selectionnumber="0" class="Event-bt9305886 RowVisible" id="Event-bt9305886">
      <td class="">
        <div class="">20:30</div>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <div class=""><img class="HS-Silk-Image" src="https://dimg-pa.googleapis.com/lg/CgYwMDAwMDA.png?sig=AI8nk_dGt7qwEVp9ek4ARNvpY1gz&key=AIzaSyCUqbG5Kw_8jb3cy2ZBKvV2kAi8z0qmQO0&sk=r7Evjfpq7nk&w=96&h=96"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="selectionContainer">
        <div class="link link_animated">Godoy Cruz v Defensa y Justicia</div>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <div class=""><img class="HS-Silk-Image" src="https://dimg-pa.googleapis.com/lg/CgYwMDAwMDA.png?sig=AI8nk_dGt7qwEVp9ek4ARNvpY1gz&key=AIzaSyCUqbG5Kw_8jb3cy2ZBKvV2kAi8z0qmQO0&sk=r7Evjfpq7nk&w=96&h=96"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine, however I need the translateX amount in the animation to be based on the width of the text, otherwise the text scrolls too far and shows whitespace.

Perhaps I need to use a bit of JS to get the width of the text or perhaps there is better way to get what im trying to achieve in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount that you need to move the text is a function of both the width of the text itself and the width of its container.

The amount that sticks out on the right hand side is (width of text - width of container).

We can use translate(100%) (or =100%) to move the text by its own width. And we can move the text to the right by the width of the container with left: 100%.

Note the text element and its container need to be position relative.

```css
.selectionContainer {
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: visible !important;
  position: relative;
}

.link_animated {
  animation: backAndForth 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes backAndForth {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 0;
  }
  45% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 100%;
  }
  55% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 100%;
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 0;
  }
}

.HS-Silk-Image {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="column-1-table" class="table HS-Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="" colspan="4">
        <div class="">Monday</div>
        <div class="HS-Going-Text">2022-06-20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="" colspan="3">
    </tr>
    <tr class="" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
      <td class="" colspan="4">
        <div class="pull-left Selection-Container">Argentina Liga Profesional de Futbol</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-selectionnumber="0" class="Event-bt9305886 RowVisible" id="Event-bt9305886">
      <td class="">
        <div class="">20:30</div>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <div class=""><img class="HS-Silk-Image" src="https://dimg-pa.googleapis.com/lg/CgYwMDAwMDA.png?sig=AI8nk_dGt7qwEVp9ek4ARNvpY1gz&key=AIzaSyCUqbG5Kw_8jb3cy2ZBKvV2kAi8z0qmQO0&sk=r7Evjfpq7nk&w=96&h=96"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="selectionContainer">
        <div class="link link_animated">Godoy Cruz v Defensa y Justicia</div>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <div class=""><img class="HS-Silk-Image" src="https://dimg-pa.googleapis.com/lg/CgYwMDAwMDA.png?sig=AI8nk_dGt7qwEVp9ek4ARNvpY1gz&key=AIzaSyCUqbG5Kw_8jb3cy2ZBKvV2kAi8z0qmQO0&sk=r7Evjfpq7nk&w=96&h=96"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.link_animated {
    animation: backAndForth 5s linear infinite;
    display: flex;
}
```

Try this, although there is still a little offset to the right